# How to check which program prevent to move the folder on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-permissions

I'm using git bash on windows 7 and I'm trying to execute this command:

```
mv divos3 projects/
```

and I got error:

```
mv: cannot move ‘divos3’ to ‘projects/divos3’: Permission denied
```

(I successfully from divos to projects so it's not /c/ permission issue).

I've closed both my editors (Nodepad++ and GNU Emacs) and kill server that was running in second window of git bash and change directory to `/c/` but I still have this error.

How can I check which file and which program prevent to move the directory?

Comment: Unlocker is a program that can do this aswell http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

Comment: @RamonRobben Check this:  [unlocker virus test](https://virustotal.com/en/file/b3284358029388637e642077f99e81e81144d8dab2f2623e263dbb5b625be746/analysis/)

Comment: @Alex 10 unknown virus scanners. I still trust my BitDefender. The Major virus scanners also don't see it as a virus. It could also false positives.I've used the program alot and never had any suspicious activity's because of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) and search for path it should show you the process that hold the files for my case it was google chrome.